# Isometry fixing an open set pointwise is identity

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space and $F$ an isometry of $X$. Suppose $F$ fixes each point of a non-empty open set $U\subset X$.

Under what conditions on $X$ does it always follow that $F=\mathrm{id}$?

I already know it holds when $X$ is a complete connected Riemannian manifold, by Theorem 6.6.10 in [Ratcliffe](http://books.google.com/books?id=JV9m8o-ok6YC&pg=PA241&lpg=PA242).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sufficient condition is that

- any two points of $X$ can be joined by a local geodesic (it does not have to be globally minimizing), and
- geodesics do not split: if two geodesics share an  arc, they coincide.

In the literature, the latter condition is usually stated simply as "[geodesics do not split](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22geodesics%20do%20not%20split%22)".

Suppose the above hold. Given any point $x\in X$, join it by a (local) geodesic to a point $y\in U$.  Its image under $F$ is also a geodesic, but since $U$ is fixed pointwise, the two geodesics coincide within $U$. Therefore, they coincide, and $F(x)=x$.

---

Here is an counterexample showing the importance of non-splitting of geodesics. Let $X$ be $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(x,0): x\ne 0\}$, with the intrinsic metric (i.e., the distance between points is the length of the shortest curve between them). This is a geodesic space: moreover, any two points are joined by a unique distance-minimizing geodesic. The map 
$F(x,y) =  (x\operatorname{sign}y , y )$ is an isometry which fixes the upper halfplane pointwise but is not the identity.

*Slight variation of the above*: To give an example where $X$ is complete, let $X=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:|y|\ge |x|\}$, also with the intrinsic metric. The same $F$ works.

---

The geodesic language is cumbersome here because in the metric space world, it usually means a globally-length-minimizing curve, while in Riemannian geometry it means a locally-minimizing curve.